# Absolute difference between neighbouring pixels

Tags: matlab, absolute-value

I currently have a problem with this paper that I am reading for my thesis. In this paper, the author states that he uses a 1D filter on each side of a block with pixels to acquire 4 points.

The paper is called: "***Simplified inter-component Depth modeling in 3D hevc***"

available from IEEE or from:

http://vclab.gist.ac.kr/papers/03/2013/S35_paper%2081.pdf .

> This filter calculates absolute differences of neighbouring pixels
>
> We calculate absolute  differences of neighbors at each side of CTLB. If pixel coordinates are noted as in `Figure 4`, `Eq. (1)` is used for top and bottom sides while `Eq. (2)` is for left and right sides. `C_hor`, `r`, `c` represents the absolute difference of its horizontally neighboring pixels for top and bottom sides where horizontal neighbors are considered.
>
> Similarly for left and right  sides, `C_ver`, `r`, `c` represents the absolute difference of vertically neighboring pixels.

Figure 4:

```
A(0,0)  A(0,1)  A(0,2)  A(0,3)  ...
A(1,0)  A(1,1)  A(1,2)  A(1,3)  ...
A(2,0)  A(2,1)  A(2,2)  A(2,3)  ...
A(3,0)  A(3,1)  A(3,2)  A(3,3)  ...
...     ...     ...     ...     ...
```

Equation 1:

```
C_hor(r,c) = |A(r,c+1) - A(r,c-1)|
```

Equation 2:

```
C_ver(r,c) = |A(r+1,c) - A(r-1,c)|
```

My question is, does anyone know how he manages to get 4 points just by using the equations above? Furthermore, what would he do for the edges as he would need the previous pixels no? I'm currently trying to implement this in C++, though a simple matlab code would also help just so i could understand it.

Thanks.

Comment: providing the paper name would help a lot. Also, please show your effort since when you ask questions.

Comment: Hi, paper is added (I didn't add it before as its from IEEE and he doesn't explain anything else apart from what is written above). The main problem is that I cant understand how he gets just 4 points from using those two equations. If some one explains that to me I would be able to code it most prob. I just mentioned Matlab as I needed to use a tag and usually Matlab is very useful for explaining stuff like this. Thnks

Answer (score 0):

Figure 4 does not contain just 4 points. There are "..." ellipses showing he means to represent all points in A.

There are numerous ways to do the computation in MATLAB. One way is by convolution,

```
 k=[1 0 -1;] 

 C_hor=abs(conv2(A,k,'same'));
 C_ver=abs(conv2(A,k.','same'));
```

Here I used the 'same' flag under the assumption that we want to extrapolate outside A with zeros at the edges.

Comment: Hi, I managed to find an online pdf version of the paper..I added it in now. To my understanding from the paper, Figure 4 can be a block size of either 4x4, 8x8, 16x16 or 32x32. He also states that by applying the 1D filter he acquires four points.

Now i'm thinking that by applying a filter similar to the one u gave in your response, he just chooses the four points from the sides with highest difference